# Automatically opening and closing a door

Tags: dc-motor, timer, 555, home-automation

I'm working on an automatic door that runs like this:

1. Receives an input trigger, probably a voltage input
2. DC motor runs in one direction for x seconds to open the door
3. Same DC motor reverses direction for x seconds to close the door
4. Standby for another trigger

The challenge here is that I can't use any microcontrollers (I'm too reliant on those things) and that everything is automated. I've done some research, so I've figured that I can control the motor direction with a H-bridge IC like an L298N, but I'm pretty confused with the timing control.

So far, I've found capacitor and 555 timing control circuits, but they are timing to ON and OFF circuits, which I'm not sure how to fit in here. I've also found a couple of time delay relays, but I don't know how those work.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Why can't you use a microcontroller?

Comment: Have you looked at commercially available automatic overhead (garage) door openers? These provide motor drive control, as well as safety reverse/shutoff to prevent the door from crushing people. Note that these devices don't run the motor for a fixed time interval, they instead sense the position of the door. When the door reaches the end of its travel, stop driving the motor. May be a good place to start, at least for defining the requirements.

Comment: I agree, the timing idea is a bit flawed. You should think about using limit switches (e.g. micro-switches). One for the closed position and one for the open position. The control will be a lot simpler with these compared to the timer approach. And I dare say a bit more predictable. If the door is being used for human traffic, there are a bunch of safety considerations and regulatory issues, even if it's one-of-a-kind.

Comment: Yes, this application would need either microswitches or a slipping clutch of some type, otherwise the motor is going to be stalling all the time. Actually a clutch might make sense anyway, in case something is in the way of the door completing its travel.

Comment: Simple method is use limit switches with reverse diode across switch. Motor runs until switch operates. When polarity is reversed diode at that end conducts and motor is driven out of what was dead zone.

Answer (score 2):

I've built a circuit in Proteus VSM for you. The circuit consists of 3 blocks:

**1) A Monostable Multivibrator** for managing trigger signals and generating enable signals:

[image]

img source: http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws

**2) An astable multivibrator** for managing open- and close-durations:

[image]
[image]

img source: http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws

NOTE: *If you want both durations to be equal then use the following:*

[image]
[image]

img source: http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws

**3) Motor Driver:**

[image]

Final circuit *(Click for full view)*:
[image]

First block is a monostable multivibrator with trigger input and "ENABLE/STOP" output. The output goes directly to the second block's ENABLE/RESET input and the motor driver's ENABLE input. The duration of ENABLE signal is the sum of on- and off-durations: \$T = 1.1 \cdot R5 \cdot C4 = 1.1 \cdot 27k \cdot 330\mu F = 9.8s\$

Second block is an astable multivibrator with equal on- and off-durations: \$T_{on} = T_{off} = 0.693 \cdot R1 \cdot C2 = 0.693 \cdot 20k \cdot 330\mu F = 5s\$.

Third block is a 2-way motor driver. Setting IN1=1 and IN2=0 forces the motor to turn on one direction; likewise setting IN1=0 and IN2=1 forces the motor to turn on the reverse direction.

Here's the Proteus VSM simulation file:
http://www.filedropper.com/m_5

Comment: Very nice answer.

Comment: I just tried the circuit today (the final image provided) but after 5s of moving in one direction the motor stopped without continuing in the other direction. I didn't find any problems with connections or the motor, so what do you think might be the problem?

Comment: I'm also using an L293D instead of an L298.

Comment: I didn't build the circuit, just made a simulation. You have the Proteus simulation file. Try it with L293D.

Comment: @thefinshark I tried on the simulation with L293D and saw no problem(s). Here's the updated simulation file: http://www.filedropper.com/mr Check your supply and cabling. Note that there are 5V and 12V supplies for the circuit.